# OS X: Suddenly only one window/application visible at the same time

Tags: macos, mission-control

I have a rather weird problem with my desktop of my MacBook Pro. I use El Capitan 10.11.15.

For reasons I don't know I'm no longer able to keep more than one running application visible at the time.

For example, if I start *Terminal*, it opens. But when I start *TextEdit*, Terminal will hide or minimize and *TexEdit* will become visible instead. The same goes for every other application.

When I open Mission Control, it also shows only one active window, no matter how many other applications are running.

I must have accidently activated it but cannot recall how. I've tried playing around with Dock and Mission Control settings, but nothing changed it.

Does anyone know how to get it back to normal so that I have more than one window/application visible at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around for hours, I found out what had caused this bug. It was one of the **autostart elements**. I don't know exactly which one it was, but after removing all and only adding what I really needed, all worked fine.

Comment: I eventually did find it out. The issue was caused by Keyboard Maestro. In its "General Settings", the option "Always Hide Other Applications" must be **unchecked**. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/ngOfw7R.jpg

Answer (score 4):

This answer lifted in its entirety from Super User : [Snow Leopard desktop - I want two files from two different applications open at the same time. Won't let me](https://superuser.com/questions/153457/snow-leopard-desktop-i-want-two-files-from-two-different-applications-open-at)

> Have you per chance turned on "[Single App
>   Mode](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20081229062620506&query=disable)"?
>   This hidden preference causes Mac OS X to hide all applications but
>   the current active one.
>
> You can tell by running the following command in Terminal.app:
>
> ```
> defaults read com.apple.dock single-app
> ```
>
> If it prints a `0`then it is not turned on. If it prints a `1` then
>   yes, it is turned on.
>
> You can disable this trick by running:
>
> ```
> defaults write com.apple.dock single-app 0
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just checked and Terminal told me it was turned off (`0`). Anything else I can try?

Comment: The only other possibility [however remote] that I can think of is that your Opt/alt key is sticking.

Answer (score 1):

I had my `Opt` key pressed causing the windows to hide when others activated. Leaving this here in case someone else comes across it.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X High Sierra, the problem was solved for me by deactiviting LiteSwitch X.  Go into System Preferences and LiteSwitch X should be on the bottom row. Open it and you can disable the app.

Comment: There is already an accepted answer to this question which has nothing to do with the app you mention. In fact, it was a completely different app altogether which caused the problem.

Comment: @Icon That's not a problem, this answer is not repeating a solution already provided